# Detectar si un archivo se esta enviando por correo

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

tengo una duda. Quisiera saber si existe una manera de detectar si un archivo esta siendo subido a una pagina o en este caso, si se esta subiendo, para enviar por correo.

Eh intentado con `FileSystemWatcher`, pero no he tenido exito :/ A clarando que es para una aplicacion de escritorio.

les dejo el codigo siguiente:

```
Private Sub Wachter()
    Dim MyWatcher As New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher() ' crea un nuevo objeto System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
    MyWatcher.Path = txtPath.Text ' directorio a monitorear
    MyWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = True ' indica si se deben monitorear los subdirectorios
    '======EVENTOS
    AddHandler MyWatcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler MyWatcher.Created, AddressOf OnCreated
    AddHandler MyWatcher.Deleted, AddressOf OnDeleted
    AddHandler MyWatcher.Renamed, AddressOf OnRenamed
    MyWatcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.DirectoryName)
    MyWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Public WChanged As Integer '1
Public WCreated As Integer '2
Public WRenamed As Integer '3
Public WDeleted As Integer '4

Public Sub SetStatics(ByVal val As Integer)
    Select Case val
        Case 1
            WChanged = WChanged + 1
        Case 2
            WCreated = WCreated + 1
        Case 3
            WRenamed = WRenamed + 1
        Case 4
            WDeleted = WDeleted + 1
    End Select
    MessageBox.Show("Changed: " & WChanged & "\nCreated: " & WCreated & "\nRenamed: " & WRenamed & "\nDeleted: " & WDeleted)
End Sub

Public Sub OnChanged(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs) ' se dispara cuando se modifica o accede a un archivo
    SetStatics(1)
End Sub
Public Sub OnDeleted(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs) ' al eliminar un archivo
    SetStatics(4)
End Sub
Public Sub OnCreated(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs) ' al crear un archivo
    SetStatics(2)
End Sub
Public Sub OnRenamed(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As RenamedEventArgs) ' renombrar un archivo
    SetStatics(3)
End Sub
```

lo que intento hacer esque al momento que lo quieran subir a gmail mi programa lo detecte.

Comment: ese codigo te hace algo?

Comment: Si, detecta si lo abren, si lo modifican y si lo borran, pero a mi me interesa cuando es cargado a internet